# How to convert this to /summon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Well i need some help with this command

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:wheat_seeds,Count:1}},{HideFlags:16,display:{Name:"Dirt"},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:grass","minecraft:dirt","minecraft:cobblestone","minecraft:planks","minecraft:sapling","minecraft:flowing_water","minecraft:water","minecraft:flowing_lava","minecraft:lava","minecraft:sand","minecraft:gravel","minecraft:gold_ore","minecraft:iron_ore","minecraft:coal_ore","minecraft:log","minecraft:leaves","minecraft:sponge","minecraft:glass","minecraft:lapis_ore","minecraft:dispenser","minecraft:sandstone","minecraft:noteblock","minecraft:bed","minecraft:golden_rail","minecraft:detector_rail","minecraft:sticky_piston","minecraft:web","minecraft:tallgrass","minecraft:deadbush","minecraft:piston","minecraft:piston_head","minecraft:wool","minecraft:yellow_flower","minecraft:red_flower","minecraft:brown_mushroom","minecraft:red_mushroom","minecraft:gold_block,","minecraft:iron_block","minecraft:double_stone_slab","minecraft:stone_slab","minecraft:brick_block","minecraft:tnt","minecraft:bookshelf","minecraft:mossy_cobblestone","minecraft:obsidian","minecraft:torch","minecraft:fire","minecraft:mob_spawner","minecraft:oak_stairs","minecraft:chest","minecraft:redstone_wire","minecraft:diamond_ore","minecraft:diamond_block","minecraft:crafting_table","minecraft:wheat","minecraft:farmland","minecraft:furnace","minecraft:lit_furnace,","minecraft:standing_sign","minecraft:wooden_door","minecraft:ladder","minecraft:rail","minecraft:stone_stairs","minecraft:wall_sign","minecraft:lever","minecraft:stone_pressure_plate","minecraft:iron_door","minecraft:wooden_pressure_plate","minecraft:redstone_ore","minecraft:lit_redstone_ore","minecraft:unlit_redstone_torch","minecraft:redstone_torch","minecraft:stone_button","minecraft:snow_layer","minecraft:ice","minecraft:snow","minecraft:cactus","minecraft:clay","minecraft:reeds","minecraft:jukebox","minecraft:fence","minecraft:pumpkin","minecraft:netherrack","minecraft:soul_sand","minecraft:glowstone","minecraft:portal","minecraft:lit_pumpkin","minecraft:cake","minecraft:unpowered_repeater","minecraft:powered_repeater","minecraft:stained_glass","minecraft:trapdoor","minecraft:monster_egg","minecraft:stonebrick","minecraft:brown_mushroom_block","minecraft:iron_bars","minecraft:glass_pane","minecraft:melon_block","minecraft:pumpkin_stem","minecraft:melon_stem","minecraft:vines","minecraft:fence_gate","minecraft:brick_stairs","minecraft:stone_brick_stairs","minecraft:mycelium","minecraft:waterlily","minecraft:nether_brick","minecraft:nether_brick_fence","minecraft:nether_brick_stairs","minecraft:nether_wart","minecraft:enchanting","minecraft:brewing_stand","minecraft:cauldron","minecraft:end_portal","minecraft:end_portal_frame","minecraft:end_stone","minecraft:dragon_egg","minecraft:redstone_lamp","minecraft:lit_redstone_lamp","minecraft:double_wooden_slab","minecraft:wooden_slab","minecraft:cocoa","minecraft:sandstone_stairs","minecraft:emerald_ore","minecraft:ender_chest","minecraft:tripwire_hook","minecraft:emerald_block","minecraft:spruce_stairs","minecraft:birch_stairs","minecraft:jungle_stairs","minecraft:command_block","minecraft:beacon","minecraft:cobblestone_wall","minecraft:flower_pot","minecraft:carrots","minecraft:potatoes","minecraft:wooden_button","minecraft:skull","minecraft:anvil","minecraft:trapped_chest","minecraft:light_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:heavy_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:unpowered_comparator","minecraft:powered_comparator","minecraft:daylight_detector","minecraft:redstone_block","minecraft:quartz_ore","minecraft:hopper","minecraft:quartz_block","minecraft:quartz_stairs","minecraft:activator_rail","minecraft:dropper","minecraft:stained_hardened_clay","minecraft:stained_glass_pane","minecraft:leaves2","minecraft:log2","minecraft:acacia_stairs","minecraft:dark_oak_stairs","minecraft:slime","minecraft:barrier","minecraft:iron_trapdoor","minecraft:prismarine","minecraft:sea_lantern","minecraft:hay_block","minecraft:carpet","minecraft:hardened_clay","minecraft:coal_block","minecraft:packed_ice","minecraft:double_plant","minecraft:standing_banner","minecraft:wall_banner","minecraft:daylight_detector_inverted","minecraft:red_sandstone","minecraft:double_sandstone_stairs","minecraft:double_stone_slab2","minecraft:spruce_fence_gate","minecraft:birch_fence_gate","minecraft:jungle_fence_gate","minecraft:dark_oak_fence_gate","minecraft:acacia_fence_gate","minecraft:spruce_fence","minecraft:birch_fence","minecraft:jungle_fence","minecraft:dark_oak_fence","minecraft:acacia_fence","minecraft:spruce_door","minecraft:birch_door","minecraft:jungle_door","minecraft:acacia_door","minecraft:dark_oak_door","minecraft:end_rod","minecraft:chorus_plant","minecraft:chorus_flower","minecraft:purpur_block","minecraft:purpur_pillar","minecraft:purpur_stairs","minecraft:purpur_double_slab","minecraft:purpur_slab","minecraft:end_bricks","minecraft:beetroots","minecraft:grass_path","minecraft:end_gateway","minecraft:frosted_ice","minecraft:magma","minecraft:nether_wart_block","minecraft:red_nether_brick","minecraft:bone_block","minecraft:observer","minecraft:white_shulker_box","minecraft:orange_shulker_box","minecraft:magenta_shulker_box","minecraft:light_blue_shulker_box","minecraft:yellow_shulker_box","minecraft:lime_shulker_box","minecraft:pink_shulker_box","minecraft:gray_shulker_box","minecraft:silver_shulker_box","minecraft:cyan_shulker_box","minecraft:purple_shulker_box","minecraft:blue_shulker_box","minecraft:brown_shulker_box","minecraft:green_shulker_box","minecraft:red_shulker_box","minecraft:black_shulker_box","minecraft:white_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:orange_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:magenta_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:light_blue_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:yellow_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:lime_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:pink_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:gray_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:light_gray_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:cyan_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:purple_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:blue_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:brown_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:green_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:red_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:black_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:concrete","minecraft:concrete_powder","minecraft:structure_block","FakeBlock","bedrock"]}
```

I want this command:

```
/replaceitem entity @a[score_block4_min=1] slot.weapon.mainhand minecraft:dirt 1 0 {HideFlags:16,display:{Name:"Dirt"},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:grass","minecraft:dirt","minecraft:cobblestone","minecraft:planks","minecraft:sapling","minecraft:flowing_water","minecraft:water","minecraft:flowing_lava","minecraft:lava","minecraft:sand","minecraft:gravel","minecraft:gold_ore","minecraft:iron_ore","minecraft:coal_ore","minecraft:log","minecraft:leaves","minecraft:sponge","minecraft:glass","minecraft:lapis_ore","minecraft:dispenser","minecraft:sandstone","minecraft:noteblock","minecraft:bed","minecraft:golden_rail","minecraft:detector_rail","minecraft:sticky_piston","minecraft:web","minecraft:tallgrass","minecraft:deadbush","minecraft:piston","minecraft:piston_head","minecraft:wool","minecraft:yellow_flower","minecraft:red_flower","minecraft:brown_mushroom","minecraft:red_mushroom","minecraft:gold_block,","minecraft:iron_block","minecraft:double_stone_slab","minecraft:stone_slab","minecraft:brick_block","minecraft:tnt","minecraft:bookshelf","minecraft:mossy_cobblestone","minecraft:obsidian","minecraft:torch","minecraft:fire","minecraft:mob_spawner","minecraft:oak_stairs","minecraft:chest","minecraft:redstone_wire","minecraft:diamond_ore","minecraft:diamond_block","minecraft:crafting_table","minecraft:wheat","minecraft:farmland","minecraft:furnace","minecraft:lit_furnace,","minecraft:standing_sign","minecraft:wooden_door","minecraft:ladder","minecraft:rail","minecraft:stone_stairs","minecraft:wall_sign","minecraft:lever","minecraft:stone_pressure_plate","minecraft:iron_door","minecraft:wooden_pressure_plate","minecraft:redstone_ore","minecraft:lit_redstone_ore","minecraft:unlit_redstone_torch","minecraft:redstone_torch","minecraft:stone_button","minecraft:snow_layer","minecraft:ice","minecraft:snow","minecraft:cactus","minecraft:clay","minecraft:reeds","minecraft:jukebox","minecraft:fence","minecraft:pumpkin","minecraft:netherrack","minecraft:soul_sand","minecraft:glowstone","minecraft:portal","minecraft:lit_pumpkin","minecraft:cake","minecraft:unpowered_repeater","minecraft:powered_repeater","minecraft:stained_glass","minecraft:trapdoor","minecraft:monster_egg","minecraft:stonebrick","minecraft:brown_mushroom_block","minecraft:iron_bars","minecraft:glass_pane","minecraft:melon_block","minecraft:pumpkin_stem","minecraft:melon_stem","minecraft:vines","minecraft:fence_gate","minecraft:brick_stairs","minecraft:stone_brick_stairs","minecraft:mycelium","minecraft:waterlily","minecraft:nether_brick","minecraft:nether_brick_fence","minecraft:nether_brick_stairs","minecraft:nether_wart","minecraft:enchanting","minecraft:brewing_stand","minecraft:cauldron","minecraft:end_portal","minecraft:end_portal_frame","minecraft:end_stone","minecraft:dragon_egg","minecraft:redstone_lamp","minecraft:lit_redstone_lamp","minecraft:double_wooden_slab","minecraft:wooden_slab","minecraft:cocoa","minecraft:sandstone_stairs","minecraft:emerald_ore","minecraft:ender_chest","minecraft:tripwire_hook","minecraft:emerald_block","minecraft:spruce_stairs","minecraft:birch_stairs","minecraft:jungle_stairs","minecraft:command_block","minecraft:beacon","minecraft:cobblestone_wall","minecraft:flower_pot","minecraft:carrots","minecraft:potatoes","minecraft:wooden_button","minecraft:skull","minecraft:anvil","minecraft:trapped_chest","minecraft:light_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:heavy_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:unpowered_comparator","minecraft:powered_comparator","minecraft:daylight_detector","minecraft:redstone_block","minecraft:quartz_ore","minecraft:hopper","minecraft:quartz_block","minecraft:quartz_stairs","minecraft:activator_rail","minecraft:dropper","minecraft:stained_hardened_clay","minecraft:stained_glass_pane","minecraft:leaves2","minecraft:log2","minecraft:acacia_stairs","minecraft:dark_oak_stairs","minecraft:slime","minecraft:barrier","minecraft:iron_trapdoor","minecraft:prismarine","minecraft:sea_lantern","minecraft:hay_block","minecraft:carpet","minecraft:hardened_clay","minecraft:coal_block","minecraft:packed_ice","minecraft:double_plant","minecraft:standing_banner","minecraft:wall_banner","minecraft:daylight_detector_inverted","minecraft:red_sandstone","minecraft:double_sandstone_stairs","minecraft:double_stone_slab2","minecraft:spruce_fence_gate","minecraft:birch_fence_gate","minecraft:jungle_fence_gate","minecraft:dark_oak_fence_gate","minecraft:acacia_fence_gate","minecraft:spruce_fence","minecraft:birch_fence","minecraft:jungle_fence","minecraft:dark_oak_fence","minecraft:acacia_fence","minecraft:spruce_door","minecraft:birch_door","minecraft:jungle_door","minecraft:acacia_door","minecraft:dark_oak_door","minecraft:end_rod","minecraft:chorus_plant","minecraft:chorus_flower","minecraft:purpur_block","minecraft:purpur_pillar","minecraft:purpur_stairs","minecraft:purpur_double_slab","minecraft:purpur_slab","minecraft:end_bricks","minecraft:beetroots","minecraft:grass_path","minecraft:end_gateway","minecraft:frosted_ice","minecraft:magma","minecraft:nether_wart_block","minecraft:red_nether_brick","minecraft:bone_block","minecraft:observer","minecraft:white_shulker_box","minecraft:orange_shulker_box","minecraft:magenta_shulker_box","minecraft:light_blue_shulker_box","minecraft:yellow_shulker_box","minecraft:lime_shulker_box","minecraft:pink_shulker_box","minecraft:gray_shulker_box","minecraft:silver_shulker_box","minecraft:cyan_shulker_box","minecraft:purple_shulker_box","minecraft:blue_shulker_box","minecraft:brown_shulker_box","minecraft:green_shulker_box","minecraft:red_shulker_box","minecraft:black_shulker_box","minecraft:white_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:orange_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:magenta_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:light_blue_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:yellow_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:lime_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:pink_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:gray_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:light_gray_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:cyan_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:purple_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:blue_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:brown_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:green_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:red_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:black_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:concrete","minecraft:concrete_powder","minecraft:structure_block","FakeBlock","bedrock"]}
```

To be a summon command! So i tried by doing this

```
       /summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:wheat_seeds,Count:1}},{HideFlags:16,display:{Name:"Dirt"},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:grass","minecraft:dirt","minecraft:cobblestone","minecraft:planks","minecraft:sapling","minecraft:flowing_water","minecraft:water","minecraft:flowing_lava","minecraft:lava","minecraft:sand","minecraft:gravel","minecraft:gold_ore","minecraft:iron_ore","minecraft:coal_ore","minecraft:log","minecraft:leaves","minecraft:sponge","minecraft:glass","minecraft:lapis_ore","minecraft:dispenser","minecraft:sandstone","minecraft:noteblock","minecraft:bed","minecraft:golden_rail","minecraft:detector_rail","minecraft:sticky_piston","minecraft:web","minecraft:tallgrass","minecraft:deadbush","minecraft:piston","minecraft:piston_head","minecraft:wool","minecraft:yellow_flower","minecraft:red_flower","minecraft:brown_mushroom","minecraft:red_mushroom","minecraft:gold_block,","minecraft:iron_block","minecraft:double_stone_slab","minecraft:stone_slab","minecraft:brick_block","minecraft:tnt","minecraft:bookshelf","minecraft:mossy_cobblestone","minecraft:obsidian","minecraft:torch","minecraft:fire","minecraft:mob_spawner","minecraft:oak_stairs","minecraft:chest","minecraft:redstone_wire","minecraft:diamond_ore","minecraft:diamond_block","minecraft:crafting_table","minecraft:wheat","minecraft:farmland","minecraft:furnace","minecraft:lit_furnace,","minecraft:standing_sign","minecraft:wooden_door","minecraft:ladder","minecraft:rail","minecraft:stone_stairs","minecraft:wall_sign","minecraft:lever","minecraft:stone_pressure_plate","minecraft:iron_door","minecraft:wooden_pressure_plate","minecraft:redstone_ore","minecraft:lit_redstone_ore","minecraft:unlit_redstone_torch","minecraft:redstone_torch","minecraft:stone_button","minecraft:snow_layer","minecraft:ice","minecraft:snow","minecraft:cactus","minecraft:clay","minecraft:reeds","minecraft:jukebox","minecraft:fence","minecraft:pumpkin","minecraft:netherrack","minecraft:soul_sand","minecraft:glowstone","minecraft:portal","minecraft:lit_pumpkin","minecraft:cake","minecraft:unpowered_repeater","minecraft:powered_repeater","minecraft:stained_glass","minecraft:trapdoor","minecraft:monster_egg","minecraft:stonebrick","minecraft:brown_mushroom_block","minecraft:iron_bars","minecraft:glass_pane","minecraft:melon_block","minecraft:pumpkin_stem","minecraft:melon_stem","minecraft:vines","minecraft:fence_gate","minecraft:brick_stairs","minecraft:stone_brick_stairs","minecraft:mycelium","minecraft:waterlily","minecraft:nether_brick","minecraft:nether_brick_fence","minecraft:nether_brick_stairs","minecraft:nether_wart","minecraft:enchanting","minecraft:brewing_stand","minecraft:cauldron","minecraft:end_portal","minecraft:end_portal_frame","minecraft:end_stone","minecraft:dragon_egg","minecraft:redstone_lamp","minecraft:lit_redstone_lamp","minecraft:double_wooden_slab","minecraft:wooden_slab","minecraft:cocoa","minecraft:sandstone_stairs","minecraft:emerald_ore","minecraft:ender_chest","minecraft:tripwire_hook","minecraft:emerald_block","minecraft:spruce_stairs","minecraft:birch_stairs","minecraft:jungle_stairs","minecraft:command_block","minecraft:beacon","minecraft:cobblestone_wall","minecraft:flower_pot","minecraft:carrots","minecraft:potatoes","minecraft:wooden_button","minecraft:skull","minecraft:anvil","minecraft:trapped_chest","minecraft:light_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:heavy_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:unpowered_comparator","minecraft:powered_comparator","minecraft:daylight_detector","minecraft:redstone_block","minecraft:quartz_ore","minecraft:hopper","minecraft:quartz_block","minecraft:quartz_stairs","minecraft:activator_rail","minecraft:dropper","minecraft:stained_hardened_clay","minecraft:stained_glass_pane","minecraft:leaves2","minecraft:log2","minecraft:acacia_stairs","minecraft:dark_oak_stairs","minecraft:slime","minecraft:barrier","minecraft:iron_trapdoor","minecraft:prismarine","minecraft:sea_lantern","minecraft:hay_block","minecraft:carpet","minecraft:hardened_clay","minecraft:coal_block","minecraft:packed_ice","minecraft:double_plant","minecraft:standing_banner","minecraft:wall_banner","minecraft:daylight_detector_inverted","minecraft:red_sandstone","minecraft:double_sandstone_stairs","minecraft:double_stone_slab2","minecraft:spruce_fence_gate","minecraft:birch_fence_gate","minecraft:jungle_fence_gate","minecraft:dark_oak_fence_gate","minecraft:acacia_fence_gate","minecraft:spruce_fence","minecraft:birch_fence","minecraft:jungle_fence","minecraft:dark_oak_fence","minecraft:acacia_fence","minecraft:spruce_door","minecraft:birch_door","minecraft:jungle_door","minecraft:acacia_door","minecraft:dark_oak_door","minecraft:end_rod","minecraft:chorus_plant","minecraft:chorus_flower","minecraft:purpur_block","minecraft:purpur_pillar","minecraft:purpur_stairs","minecraft:purpur_double_slab","minecraft:purpur_slab","minecraft:end_bricks","minecraft:beetroots","minecraft:grass_path","minecraft:end_gateway","minecraft:frosted_ice","minecraft:magma","minecraft:nether_wart_block","minecraft:red_nether_brick","minecraft:bone_block","minecraft:observer","minecraft:white_shulker_box","minecraft:orange_shulker_box","minecraft:magenta_shulker_box","minecraft:light_blue_shulker_box","minecraft:yellow_shulker_box","minecraft:lime_shulker_box","minecraft:pink_shulker_box","minecraft:gray_shulker_box","minecraft:silver_shulker_box","minecraft:cyan_shulker_box","minecraft:purple_shulker_box","minecraft:blue_shulker_box","minecraft:brown_shulker_box","minecraft:green_shulker_box","minecraft:red_shulker_box","minecraft:black_shulker_box","minecraft:white_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:orange_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:magenta_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:light_blue_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:yellow_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:lime_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:pink_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:gray_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:light_gray_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:cyan_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:purple_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:blue_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:brown_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:green_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:red_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:black_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:concrete","minecraft:concrete_powder","minecraft:structure_block","FakeBlock","bedrock"]}
```

might help:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:wheat_seeds,Count:1}}

/replaceitem entity @a[score_block4_min=1] slot.weapon.mainhand minecraft:dirt 1 0 {HideFlags:16,display:{Name:"Dirt"},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:grass","minecraft:dirt","minecraft:cobblestone","minecraft:planks","minecraft:sapling","minecraft:flowing_water","minecraft:water","minecraft:flowing_lava","minecraft:lava","minecraft:sand","minecraft:gravel","minecraft:gold_ore","minecraft:iron_ore","minecraft:coal_ore","minecraft:log","minecraft:leaves","minecraft:sponge","minecraft:glass","minecraft:lapis_ore","minecraft:dispenser","minecraft:sandstone","minecraft:noteblock","minecraft:bed","minecraft:golden_rail","minecraft:detector_rail","minecraft:sticky_piston","minecraft:web","minecraft:tallgrass","minecraft:deadbush","minecraft:piston","minecraft:piston_head","minecraft:wool","minecraft:yellow_flower","minecraft:red_flower","minecraft:brown_mushroom","minecraft:red_mushroom","minecraft:gold_block,","minecraft:iron_block","minecraft:double_stone_slab","minecraft:stone_slab","minecraft:brick_block","minecraft:tnt","minecraft:bookshelf","minecraft:mossy_cobblestone","minecraft:obsidian","minecraft:torch","minecraft:fire","minecraft:mob_spawner","minecraft:oak_stairs","minecraft:chest","minecraft:redstone_wire","minecraft:diamond_ore","minecraft:diamond_block","minecraft:crafting_table","minecraft:wheat","minecraft:farmland","minecraft:furnace","minecraft:lit_furnace,","minecraft:standing_sign","minecraft:wooden_door","minecraft:ladder","minecraft:rail","minecraft:stone_stairs","minecraft:wall_sign","minecraft:lever","minecraft:stone_pressure_plate","minecraft:iron_door","minecraft:wooden_pressure_plate","minecraft:redstone_ore","minecraft:lit_redstone_ore","minecraft:unlit_redstone_torch","minecraft:redstone_torch","minecraft:stone_button","minecraft:snow_layer","minecraft:ice","minecraft:snow","minecraft:cactus","minecraft:clay","minecraft:reeds","minecraft:jukebox","minecraft:fence","minecraft:pumpkin","minecraft:netherrack","minecraft:soul_sand","minecraft:glowstone","minecraft:portal","minecraft:lit_pumpkin","minecraft:cake","minecraft:unpowered_repeater","minecraft:powered_repeater","minecraft:stained_glass","minecraft:trapdoor","minecraft:monster_egg","minecraft:stonebrick","minecraft:brown_mushroom_block","minecraft:iron_bars","minecraft:glass_pane","minecraft:melon_block","minecraft:pumpkin_stem","minecraft:melon_stem","minecraft:vines","minecraft:fence_gate","minecraft:brick_stairs","minecraft:stone_brick_stairs","minecraft:mycelium","minecraft:waterlily","minecraft:nether_brick","minecraft:nether_brick_fence","minecraft:nether_brick_stairs","minecraft:nether_wart","minecraft:enchanting","minecraft:brewing_stand","minecraft:cauldron","minecraft:end_portal","minecraft:end_portal_frame","minecraft:end_stone","minecraft:dragon_egg","minecraft:redstone_lamp","minecraft:lit_redstone_lamp","minecraft:double_wooden_slab","minecraft:wooden_slab","minecraft:cocoa","minecraft:sandstone_stairs","minecraft:emerald_ore","minecraft:ender_chest","minecraft:tripwire_hook","minecraft:emerald_block","minecraft:spruce_stairs","minecraft:birch_stairs","minecraft:jungle_stairs","minecraft:command_block","minecraft:beacon","minecraft:cobblestone_wall","minecraft:flower_pot","minecraft:carrots","minecraft:potatoes","minecraft:wooden_button","minecraft:skull","minecraft:anvil","minecraft:trapped_chest","minecraft:light_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:heavy_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:unpowered_comparator","minecraft:powered_comparator","minecraft:daylight_detector","minecraft:redstone_block","minecraft:quartz_ore","minecraft:hopper","minecraft:quartz_block","minecraft:quartz_stairs","minecraft:activator_rail","minecraft:dropper","minecraft:stained_hardened_clay","minecraft:stained_glass_pane","minecraft:leaves2","minecraft:log2","minecraft:acacia_stairs","minecraft:dark_oak_stairs","minecraft:slime","minecraft:barrier","minecraft:iron_trapdoor","minecraft:prismarine","minecraft:sea_lantern","minecraft:hay_block","minecraft:carpet","minecraft:hardened_clay","minecraft:coal_block","minecraft:packed_ice","minecraft:double_plant","minecraft:standing_banner","minecraft:wall_banner","minecraft:daylight_detector_inverted","minecraft:red_sandstone","minecraft:double_sandstone_stairs","minecraft:double_stone_slab2","minecraft:spruce_fence_gate","minecraft:birch_fence_gate","minecraft:jungle_fence_gate","minecraft:dark_oak_fence_gate","minecraft:acacia_fence_gate","minecraft:spruce_fence","minecraft:birch_fence","minecraft:jungle_fence","minecraft:dark_oak_fence","minecraft:acacia_fence","minecraft:spruce_door","minecraft:birch_door","minecraft:jungle_door","minecraft:acacia_door","minecraft:dark_oak_door","minecraft:end_rod","minecraft:chorus_plant","minecraft:chorus_flower","minecraft:purpur_block","minecraft:purpur_pillar","minecraft:purpur_stairs","minecraft:purpur_double_slab","minecraft:purpur_slab","minecraft:end_bricks","minecraft:beetroots","minecraft:grass_path","minecraft:end_gateway","minecraft:frosted_ice","minecraft:magma","minecraft:nether_wart_block","minecraft:red_nether_brick","minecraft:bone_block","minecraft:observer","minecraft:white_shulker_box","minecraft:orange_shulker_box","minecraft:magenta_shulker_box","minecraft:light_blue_shulker_box","minecraft:yellow_shulker_box","minecraft:lime_shulker_box","minecraft:pink_shulker_box","minecraft:gray_shulker_box","minecraft:silver_shulker_box","minecraft:cyan_shulker_box","minecraft:purple_shulker_box","minecraft:blue_shulker_box","minecraft:brown_shulker_box","minecraft:green_shulker_box","minecraft:red_shulker_box","minecraft:black_shulker_box","minecraft:white_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:orange_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:magenta_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:light_blue_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:yellow_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:lime_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:pink_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:gray_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:light_gray_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:cyan_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:purple_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:blue_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:brown_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:green_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:red_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:black_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:concrete","minecraft:concrete_powder","minecraft:structure_block","FakeBlock","bedrock"]}
```

Okay let me clerify. I just want to be able to summon a block with a CanPlaceOn tag. Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, but nobody can help you with such long commands. Do you expect us to analyse every single character for correctness? Please first shorten the command, make the short one work, then add details back in. Otherwise you can have thousands of different problems and nobody knows which one. Also, you wrote what you tried, that's good. But why does that not satisfy your need? Does the wrong thing happen? Does nothing happen? Do you get an error message? What should your command even do? Why does it need to be so long? In short: More text, less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the tag compound in order to add CanPlaceOn and HideFlags as they are part of the item's dataTag.  Also, in the CanPlaceOn list you had `FakeBlock` which I removed and `bedrock` which I changed to `minecraft:bedrock`.

I am guessing the summon seeds command you tried came from the summon item command you posted second.  I didn't think you actually wanted seeds which were named dirt so this command will summon a dirt block with the data:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:dirt",Count:1b,tag:{HideFlags:16,CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:grass","minecraft:dirt","minecraft:cobblestone","minecraft:planks","minecraft:sapling","minecraft:flowing_water","minecraft:water","minecraft:flowing_lava","minecraft:lava","minecraft:sand","minecraft:gravel","minecraft:gold_ore","minecraft:iron_ore","minecraft:coal_ore","minecraft:log","minecraft:leaves","minecraft:sponge","minecraft:glass","minecraft:lapis_ore","minecraft:dispenser","minecraft:sandstone","minecraft:noteblock","minecraft:bed","minecraft:golden_rail","minecraft:detector_rail","minecraft:sticky_piston","minecraft:web","minecraft:tallgrass","minecraft:deadbush","minecraft:piston","minecraft:piston_head","minecraft:wool","minecraft:yellow_flower","minecraft:red_flower","minecraft:brown_mushroom","minecraft:red_mushroom","minecraft:gold_block,","minecraft:iron_block","minecraft:double_stone_slab","minecraft:stone_slab","minecraft:brick_block","minecraft:tnt","minecraft:bookshelf","minecraft:mossy_cobblestone","minecraft:obsidian","minecraft:torch","minecraft:fire","minecraft:mob_spawner","minecraft:oak_stairs","minecraft:chest","minecraft:redstone_wire","minecraft:diamond_ore","minecraft:diamond_block","minecraft:crafting_table","minecraft:wheat","minecraft:farmland","minecraft:furnace","minecraft:lit_furnace,","minecraft:standing_sign","minecraft:wooden_door","minecraft:ladder","minecraft:rail","minecraft:stone_stairs","minecraft:wall_sign","minecraft:lever","minecraft:stone_pressure_plate","minecraft:iron_door","minecraft:wooden_pressure_plate","minecraft:redstone_ore","minecraft:lit_redstone_ore","minecraft:unlit_redstone_torch","minecraft:redstone_torch","minecraft:stone_button","minecraft:snow_layer","minecraft:ice","minecraft:snow","minecraft:cactus","minecraft:clay","minecraft:reeds","minecraft:jukebox","minecraft:fence","minecraft:pumpkin","minecraft:netherrack","minecraft:soul_sand","minecraft:glowstone","minecraft:portal","minecraft:lit_pumpkin","minecraft:cake","minecraft:unpowered_repeater","minecraft:powered_repeater","minecraft:stained_glass","minecraft:trapdoor","minecraft:monster_egg","minecraft:stonebrick","minecraft:brown_mushroom_block","minecraft:iron_bars","minecraft:glass_pane","minecraft:melon_block","minecraft:pumpkin_stem","minecraft:melon_stem","minecraft:vines","minecraft:fence_gate","minecraft:brick_stairs","minecraft:stone_brick_stairs","minecraft:mycelium","minecraft:waterlily","minecraft:nether_brick","minecraft:nether_brick_fence","minecraft:nether_brick_stairs","minecraft:nether_wart","minecraft:enchanting","minecraft:brewing_stand","minecraft:cauldron","minecraft:end_portal","minecraft:end_portal_frame","minecraft:end_stone","minecraft:dragon_egg","minecraft:redstone_lamp","minecraft:lit_redstone_lamp","minecraft:double_wooden_slab","minecraft:wooden_slab","minecraft:cocoa","minecraft:sandstone_stairs","minecraft:emerald_ore","minecraft:ender_chest","minecraft:tripwire_hook","minecraft:emerald_block","minecraft:spruce_stairs","minecraft:birch_stairs","minecraft:jungle_stairs","minecraft:command_block","minecraft:beacon","minecraft:cobblestone_wall","minecraft:flower_pot","minecraft:carrots","minecraft:potatoes","minecraft:wooden_button","minecraft:skull","minecraft:anvil","minecraft:trapped_chest","minecraft:light_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:heavy_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:unpowered_comparator","minecraft:powered_comparator","minecraft:daylight_detector","minecraft:redstone_block","minecraft:quartz_ore","minecraft:hopper","minecraft:quartz_block","minecraft:quartz_stairs","minecraft:activator_rail","minecraft:dropper","minecraft:stained_hardened_clay","minecraft:stained_glass_pane","minecraft:leaves2","minecraft:log2","minecraft:acacia_stairs","minecraft:dark_oak_stairs","minecraft:slime","minecraft:barrier","minecraft:iron_trapdoor","minecraft:prismarine","minecraft:sea_lantern","minecraft:hay_block","minecraft:carpet","minecraft:hardened_clay","minecraft:coal_block","minecraft:packed_ice","minecraft:double_plant","minecraft:standing_banner","minecraft:wall_banner","minecraft:daylight_detector_inverted","minecraft:red_sandstone","minecraft:double_sandstone_stairs","minecraft:double_stone_slab2","minecraft:spruce_fence_gate","minecraft:birch_fence_gate","minecraft:jungle_fence_gate","minecraft:dark_oak_fence_gate","minecraft:acacia_fence_gate","minecraft:spruce_fence","minecraft:birch_fence","minecraft:jungle_fence","minecraft:dark_oak_fence","minecraft:acacia_fence","minecraft:spruce_door","minecraft:birch_door","minecraft:jungle_door","minecraft:acacia_door","minecraft:dark_oak_door","minecraft:end_rod","minecraft:chorus_plant","minecraft:chorus_flower","minecraft:purpur_block","minecraft:purpur_pillar","minecraft:purpur_stairs","minecraft:purpur_double_slab","minecraft:purpur_slab","minecraft:end_bricks","minecraft:beetroots","minecraft:grass_path","minecraft:end_gateway","minecraft:frosted_ice","minecraft:magma","minecraft:nether_wart_block","minecraft:red_nether_brick","minecraft:bone_block","minecraft:observer","minecraft:white_shulker_box","minecraft:orange_shulker_box","minecraft:magenta_shulker_box","minecraft:light_blue_shulker_box","minecraft:yellow_shulker_box","minecraft:lime_shulker_box","minecraft:pink_shulker_box","minecraft:gray_shulker_box","minecraft:silver_shulker_box","minecraft:cyan_shulker_box","minecraft:purple_shulker_box","minecraft:blue_shulker_box","minecraft:brown_shulker_box","minecraft:green_shulker_box","minecraft:red_shulker_box","minecraft:black_shulker_box","minecraft:white_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:orange_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:magenta_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:light_blue_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:yellow_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:lime_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:pink_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:gray_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:light_gray_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:cyan_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:purple_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:blue_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:brown_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:green_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:red_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:black_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:concrete","minecraft:concrete_powder","minecraft:structure_block","minecraft:bedrock"]}}}
```

Just in case you actually wanted it, this command summons wheat seeds named Dirt with the data:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:wheat_seeds",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"Dirt"},HideFlags:16,CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:grass","minecraft:dirt","minecraft:cobblestone","minecraft:planks","minecraft:sapling","minecraft:flowing_water","minecraft:water","minecraft:flowing_lava","minecraft:lava","minecraft:sand","minecraft:gravel","minecraft:gold_ore","minecraft:iron_ore","minecraft:coal_ore","minecraft:log","minecraft:leaves","minecraft:sponge","minecraft:glass","minecraft:lapis_ore","minecraft:dispenser","minecraft:sandstone","minecraft:noteblock","minecraft:bed","minecraft:golden_rail","minecraft:detector_rail","minecraft:sticky_piston","minecraft:web","minecraft:tallgrass","minecraft:deadbush","minecraft:piston","minecraft:piston_head","minecraft:wool","minecraft:yellow_flower","minecraft:red_flower","minecraft:brown_mushroom","minecraft:red_mushroom","minecraft:gold_block,","minecraft:iron_block","minecraft:double_stone_slab","minecraft:stone_slab","minecraft:brick_block","minecraft:tnt","minecraft:bookshelf","minecraft:mossy_cobblestone","minecraft:obsidian","minecraft:torch","minecraft:fire","minecraft:mob_spawner","minecraft:oak_stairs","minecraft:chest","minecraft:redstone_wire","minecraft:diamond_ore","minecraft:diamond_block","minecraft:crafting_table","minecraft:wheat","minecraft:farmland","minecraft:furnace","minecraft:lit_furnace,","minecraft:standing_sign","minecraft:wooden_door","minecraft:ladder","minecraft:rail","minecraft:stone_stairs","minecraft:wall_sign","minecraft:lever","minecraft:stone_pressure_plate","minecraft:iron_door","minecraft:wooden_pressure_plate","minecraft:redstone_ore","minecraft:lit_redstone_ore","minecraft:unlit_redstone_torch","minecraft:redstone_torch","minecraft:stone_button","minecraft:snow_layer","minecraft:ice","minecraft:snow","minecraft:cactus","minecraft:clay","minecraft:reeds","minecraft:jukebox","minecraft:fence","minecraft:pumpkin","minecraft:netherrack","minecraft:soul_sand","minecraft:glowstone","minecraft:portal","minecraft:lit_pumpkin","minecraft:cake","minecraft:unpowered_repeater","minecraft:powered_repeater","minecraft:stained_glass","minecraft:trapdoor","minecraft:monster_egg","minecraft:stonebrick","minecraft:brown_mushroom_block","minecraft:iron_bars","minecraft:glass_pane","minecraft:melon_block","minecraft:pumpkin_stem","minecraft:melon_stem","minecraft:vines","minecraft:fence_gate","minecraft:brick_stairs","minecraft:stone_brick_stairs","minecraft:mycelium","minecraft:waterlily","minecraft:nether_brick","minecraft:nether_brick_fence","minecraft:nether_brick_stairs","minecraft:nether_wart","minecraft:enchanting","minecraft:brewing_stand","minecraft:cauldron","minecraft:end_portal","minecraft:end_portal_frame","minecraft:end_stone","minecraft:dragon_egg","minecraft:redstone_lamp","minecraft:lit_redstone_lamp","minecraft:double_wooden_slab","minecraft:wooden_slab","minecraft:cocoa","minecraft:sandstone_stairs","minecraft:emerald_ore","minecraft:ender_chest","minecraft:tripwire_hook","minecraft:emerald_block","minecraft:spruce_stairs","minecraft:birch_stairs","minecraft:jungle_stairs","minecraft:command_block","minecraft:beacon","minecraft:cobblestone_wall","minecraft:flower_pot","minecraft:carrots","minecraft:potatoes","minecraft:wooden_button","minecraft:skull","minecraft:anvil","minecraft:trapped_chest","minecraft:light_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:heavy_weighted_pressure_plate","minecraft:unpowered_comparator","minecraft:powered_comparator","minecraft:daylight_detector","minecraft:redstone_block","minecraft:quartz_ore","minecraft:hopper","minecraft:quartz_block","minecraft:quartz_stairs","minecraft:activator_rail","minecraft:dropper","minecraft:stained_hardened_clay","minecraft:stained_glass_pane","minecraft:leaves2","minecraft:log2","minecraft:acacia_stairs","minecraft:dark_oak_stairs","minecraft:slime","minecraft:barrier","minecraft:iron_trapdoor","minecraft:prismarine","minecraft:sea_lantern","minecraft:hay_block","minecraft:carpet","minecraft:hardened_clay","minecraft:coal_block","minecraft:packed_ice","minecraft:double_plant","minecraft:standing_banner","minecraft:wall_banner","minecraft:daylight_detector_inverted","minecraft:red_sandstone","minecraft:double_sandstone_stairs","minecraft:double_stone_slab2","minecraft:spruce_fence_gate","minecraft:birch_fence_gate","minecraft:jungle_fence_gate","minecraft:dark_oak_fence_gate","minecraft:acacia_fence_gate","minecraft:spruce_fence","minecraft:birch_fence","minecraft:jungle_fence","minecraft:dark_oak_fence","minecraft:acacia_fence","minecraft:spruce_door","minecraft:birch_door","minecraft:jungle_door","minecraft:acacia_door","minecraft:dark_oak_door","minecraft:end_rod","minecraft:chorus_plant","minecraft:chorus_flower","minecraft:purpur_block","minecraft:purpur_pillar","minecraft:purpur_stairs","minecraft:purpur_double_slab","minecraft:purpur_slab","minecraft:end_bricks","minecraft:beetroots","minecraft:grass_path","minecraft:end_gateway","minecraft:frosted_ice","minecraft:magma","minecraft:nether_wart_block","minecraft:red_nether_brick","minecraft:bone_block","minecraft:observer","minecraft:white_shulker_box","minecraft:orange_shulker_box","minecraft:magenta_shulker_box","minecraft:light_blue_shulker_box","minecraft:yellow_shulker_box","minecraft:lime_shulker_box","minecraft:pink_shulker_box","minecraft:gray_shulker_box","minecraft:silver_shulker_box","minecraft:cyan_shulker_box","minecraft:purple_shulker_box","minecraft:blue_shulker_box","minecraft:brown_shulker_box","minecraft:green_shulker_box","minecraft:red_shulker_box","minecraft:black_shulker_box","minecraft:white_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:orange_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:magenta_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:light_blue_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:yellow_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:lime_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:pink_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:gray_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:light_gray_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:cyan_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:purple_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:blue_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:brown_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:green_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:red_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:black_glazed_terracotta","minecraft:concrete","minecraft:concrete_powder","minecraft:structure_block","minecraft:bedrock"]}}}
```